# search existing bookmark url in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I'm developing a chrome extension related to bookmark,  I have fetched the current page url in a variable, with that I need to compare url with exiting bookmarks url. my extension is restricted to single folder in bookmark. i've the ID of the folder. how to search the presence of an existing url within a folder using search function in chrome as below:

```
chrome.bookmarks.search(query, function(results) {

});
```

Thanks